# Neo4j nodes weighting

Tags: database-design, neo4j

Given a movie database, is it possible to weight each nodes based on the presence of certain actors and their respective presence in % of film minutes, returning only nodes above a specified threshold? Please provide an example (general) query.

Es:

```
Threshold: 600 (entered dynamically, not present in DB)

Actor: Good Guy
Val: +12 (entered dynamically, not present in DB)

Actor: Bad Guy
Val: -2 (entered dynamically, not present in DB)

Movie: Nice Movie
Length: 120min
Good Guy presence: 70min
Bad Guy presence: 10min

Val: 120/70*100*(+12) + 120/10*100*(-2)
If Val > 600 then return the node
```

Also, is Neo4j an appropriate database for this kind of operations or is Mysql superior for this kind of usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neo is a good choice for this sort of thing. See the cineasts example graph they built: 
http://www.neo4j.org/develop/example_data
http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/neo4j/docs/dev/reference/pdf/spring-data-neo4j-tutorial.pdf

You would want to make the weight a property the relationships between the actors and the movies, rather than the nodes.

Answer (score 1):

This is more a design question rather then one of the database you choose, but yes, neo4j would be a good candidate as it's a property graph and you can store things like weight as a property of a node or relationships.

That being said, you'll probably want to put the weight on the relationship rather then the node, this way you can do an easy search on both the actor/actress and the movie, as a sort of aggregate.